# Lottie and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, lottie

I’m using [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) animations inside the ViewHolder of a RecyclerView. When scrolling, the frame rate is too low. This happens even with animations paused.

Any suggestion or solution to this problem?

Comment: (What does `frame rate` refer to with `animations paused`?)

Comment: Hi @greybeard ! I'm referring to the recyclerView scroll.

Answer (score 2):

You should stop the animation if the `ViewHolder` is recycled.

Override in RecyclerView adapter

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);

    holder.mLottieView.cancelAnimation();

    Drawable drawable = holder.mLottieView.getDrawable();
    if (drawable instanceof LottieDrawable) {
        ((LottieDrawable) drawable).clearComposition();
    }
}
```

I clear the composition inside the `LottieDrawable` so they don't store anything inside, it also calls a private method `clearBitmaps`, which may help wipe some memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Attribute called `Cache Strategy` which Cache the Animation for the first time  to make a Smooth Animation

its Default value is `weak`  but you can change the Value to  `strong` to be like this

> app:lottie_cacheStrategy="none"
>
> app:lottie_cacheStrategy="weak"
>
> app:lottie_cacheStrategy="strong"

take A look at this [Performance](http://airbnb.io/lottie/android/performance.html) Discussion it may be Useful if Caching
Didn't work