# LottieAnimationView doesn't start animation after setImageResource

Tags: android, android-animation, lottie

I have the following code:

```
if (isExtracting) {
    extractionButton.cancelAnimation()
    extractionButton.repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
    extractionButton?.let { extractionButton.setComposition(composition) }
    extractionButton.playAnimation()
} else {
    extractionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.extraction_button_background)
}
```

When I run the animation first, everything works correctly. However, when the state changes and the image is set and afterwards the state changes again and the animation should restart, the animation won't load. And the image is shown instead.

Any idea how to run the animation again?

Comment: That's strange. It worked for me. Can you please make sure that `isExtracting` becomes true again? & there is no other state change afterward? I've created a sample & I toggle `isExtracting` to mimic state change & it works.

Comment: This is the result: https://gifyu.com/image/SbX7U

Comment: that's weird, I agree. Can you share with me the code you used? (also only the class with the lottie logic is fine). Maybe you are loading the composition in a different way, I don't know. IsExtracting should work fine. I'm going to test it again in a minute though. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Sure. I'll post it in the answers section. As it won't fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it. Making sure that `isExtracting` flag toggles after some time to mimic the state change.

**XML:**

```
 <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/extractionButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/camera"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="false"/>
```

**Activity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var isExtracting = true
    private val extractionButton: LottieAnimationView by lazy { findViewById(R.id.extractionButton) }
    private lateinit var composition: LottieComposition

    private var job: Job? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //change R.raw.camera with your lottie file
        LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawRes(this,R.raw.camera).addListener {
            it?.let {
                composition = it
                play()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun play() {
        if (isExtracting) {
            extractionButton.cancelAnimation()
            extractionButton.repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
            extractionButton.setComposition(composition)
            extractionButton.playAnimation()
            toggleAfterDelay()
        } else {
            //change R.drawable.ic_android with your drawable
            extractionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_android)
            toggleAfterDelay()
        }
    }

    private fun toggleAfterDelay() {
        job?.cancel()
        job = MainScope().launch {
            delay(3000)
            isExtracting = !isExtracting
            play()
        }
    }



}
```

Try running this in an isolated environment(just a new project with `Lottie`) & see the result.

**Output:**

https://gifyu.com/image/SbX7U

Comment: I've copied your code that seems 100% fine to me but I'm still not able to make it work. Are you sure that the animation starts every time (so not only the first time)? Unfortunately from the gif I cannot understand whether it's just the same animation in loop or it's multiple times. Because the first run works ok for me, it's the second that it doesn't work :( and my code is 100% equals to yours right now :( I'm also sure that isExtracting is to true since I used the debugger.

Comment: @Filnik Yes. I can confirm that animation is playing every time. I added `addAnimatorListener` on `extractionButton`  it calls `onAnimationRepeat` in all the cases.

Comment: @Filnik 2 questions though: 1) What version of Lottie are you using? 2) Would you be able to provide the animation file(or link) that I can test at my end?

Comment: I've found the reason why it wasn't working for me. But I accepted your answer since it was correct. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Mayur was right. However, I put the image in a recycler view. So for this reason, I had also to follow [this suggestion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50446648/lottie-and-recyclerview)

So I needed to add this method in my ViewHolder:

```
fun clearAnimation() {
    binding.extractionButton.cancelAnimation()

    val drawable: Drawable? = binding.extractionButton.drawable
    if (drawable is LottieDrawable) {
        drawable.clearComposition()
    }
}
```

and this code to the RecyclerAdapter:

```
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder)

    if (holder is MyViewHolder) {
        holder.clearAnimation()
    }
}
```

However, since Mayur was right and his answer helped me a lot, I accepted his answer :-)